# Import C# .NET dll into tlb delphi - "cannot find specified file. ClassID {reg value}"

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, import, tlb

I tried to import .dll file (made in `.NET 4 C#`) into `Delphi (xe7)` type library.
I registered it by

`regasm (regasm <filepath>\library.dll -tlb /codebase)`

and import to `Delphi`

`(Import Component>Import Type Library)`

For these operations I have got state:

> success.

But when I'm trying to use it I have got error:

> "Cannot find specified file. ClassId: {registry value}".

I check registry, and I have got these value, everything looks fine.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: is the .NET DLL 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: 32 bit, and delphi app also 32bit, and system win 10 32bit

Comment: How did you compile the .NET dll, AnyCPU or X86?

Comment: It isn't mine dll, I get it "as is" with other product, so I can't answear. All I know that is they made it on .net 40 in c# and compiled for 32bit architecture. For x64 I have got other dll version

Comment: Now I got details: Name                  : MRR
Version               : 1.0.0.0
CultureInfo           :
CultureName           :
CodeBase              : file:///C:/Users/Maniu/Downloads/Files/MRR.dll
EscapedCodeBase       : file:///C:/Users/Maniu/Downloads/Files/MRR.dll
ProcessorArchitecture : MSIL
ContentType           : Default
Flags                 : PublicKey
HashAlgorithm         : SHA1
VersionCompatibility  : SameMachine
KeyPair               :
FullName              : MRR, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1f4d31838d